# Dificuldade ao montar query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Opa pessoal.
Estou tendo dificuldade para montar uma query no MySQL.

É o seguinte, tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura

[image: tabela]

As colunas time_laranja e time_azul armazenam ID's de usuários do sistema.

Eu preciso buscar nas colunas time_laranja e time_azul um ID específico. 
Por exemplo, meu usuário tem como ID o número 5.
Eu preciso verificar em quais linhas existem o número 5 no time_laranja ou no time_azul.

Eu não consegui montar nada, desculpe :(

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que a estrutura da sua tabela seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_partida
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  time_laranja TEXT,
  time_azul TEXT,
  capitao_azul INTEGER,
  capitao_laranja INTEGER,
  placar TEXT,
  finalizado INTEGER
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO
  tb_partida ( id, time_laranja, time_azul, capitao_azul, capitao_laranja, placar, finalizado )
VALUES
  ( 15, '7,5,11,8,9',  '1,4,6,2,3',  6, 11, '2x4', 1 ),
  ( 16, '3,7,11,6,8',  '5,2,4,9,1',  1, 11, '4x5', 1 ),
  ( 17, '6,8,11,2,9',  '1,4,5,3,7',  1, 11, '1x3', 1 ),
  ( 18, '3,9,8,6,11',  '7,2,4,1,5',  1, 11, '4x8', 1 ),
  ( 19,  '2,7,9,1,6', '11,3,4,5,8', 11,  1, '4x8', 1 ),
  ( 20,  '7,5,2,1,6', '4,8,3,11,9', 11,  1, '4x3', 1 ),
  ( 21,  '4,1,3,5,8', '7,2,11,6,9', 11,  1, '9x1', 1 ),
  ( 22,  '4,1,8,7,5', '2,11,3,9,6', 11,  1,   '0', 0 ),
  ( 23, '11,5,8,6,3',  '2,1,9,7,4',  1, 11, '1x6', 1 );
```

No `MySQL`, você pode usar a função [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) para verificar se um determinado valor está contido em uma lista de valores separados por vírgula (`,`).

Para recuperar as `Partidas` que o `Jogador` de identificador `5` participou no `Time Laranja`:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_partida WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '5', time_laranja );
```

Saída:

```
| id | time_laranja |  time_azul | capitao_azul | capitao_laranja | placar | finalizado |
|----|--------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|--------|------------|
| 15 |   7,5,11,8,9 |  1,4,6,2,3 |            6 |              11 |    2x4 |          1 |
| 20 |    7,5,2,1,6 | 4,8,3,11,9 |           11 |               1 |    4x3 |          1 |
| 21 |    4,1,3,5,8 | 7,2,11,6,9 |           11 |               1 |    9x1 |          1 |
| 22 |    4,1,8,7,5 | 2,11,3,9,6 |           11 |               1 |      0 |          0 |
| 23 |   11,5,8,6,3 |  2,1,9,7,4 |            1 |              11 |    1x6 |          1 |
```

Para recuperar as `Partidas` que o `Jogador` de identificador `5` participou no `Time Azul`:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_partida WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '5', time_azul );
```

Saída:

```
| id | time_laranja |  time_azul | capitao_azul | capitao_laranja | placar | finalizado |
|----|--------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|--------|------------|
| 16 |   3,7,11,6,8 |  5,2,4,9,1 |            1 |              11 |    4x5 |          1 |
| 17 |   6,8,11,2,9 |  1,4,5,3,7 |            1 |              11 |    1x3 |          1 |
| 18 |   3,9,8,6,11 |  7,2,4,1,5 |            1 |              11 |    4x8 |          1 |
| 19 |    2,7,9,1,6 | 11,3,4,5,8 |           11 |               1 |    4x8 |          1 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFidle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1464c9/4)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei a função FIND_IN_SET do Mysql
Documentação para quem quiser:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp

Comment: Sim, existem muitas soluções para este problema, mas o maior problema é a estrutura em que esta tabela foi montada, que exige uma varredura de todos os registros da tabela para encontrar os resultados. 
Imagino que para esta solução, que certamente são poucos registros, a performance não atrapalha em nada. 
Mas se fosse uma  tabela com milhões de registros, haveria uma sensível demora. 
O correto seria fazer tabelas adicionais relacionadas a esta, onde a pesquisa seria usada por índices, onde aí a velocidade não seria comprometida.

Comment: Eu já tentei usar índices, mas sem sucesso, não consigo entender.

Answer (score -1):

`Select * from tabela where time_azul rlike '([^0-9]|^)5([^0-9]|$)' and time_laranja rlike '([^0-9]|^)5([^0-9]|$)'`

Isso atende sua necessidade, no entanto sua tabela está mal modelada. É interessante você estudar como faz uma boa modelagem de banco e as regras que definem a `forma normal`.

Comment: Like não funciona. Pois se existir um ID: 547, ele vai selecionar essa linha, por conta do 5

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora atende sua necessidade, lembrando que essa query não é eficiente, mas é o que atende a sua modelagem.

Comment: eu encontrei uma função chamada FIND_IN_SET que é usada para strings com vírgula no SQL, mas obrigado :) vou postar caso alguem precise